# How to disable jDaychooser

Tags: java

I am using a JDateChooser. How do I disable editing option on the text field that appears? It canot be change.

```
JDateChooser chooser = new JDateChooser();
chooser.disable();
```

Comment: Which text field are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that.

```
JDateChooser chooser = new JDateChooser();
chooser.setEnabled(false);
```